# Pass variable to other page with get method

Tags: php, mysql

I am starting to study Php e MySql. I create this simple form to pass with Get data from a page to another page. Why don't run?
This is eta.html

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="get"> 
Eta' : <input type="text" name="eta"/> 
<br> 
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/> 
<br> 
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia Form"/> 
</form>
```

This is pagina.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['eta'] ."<br />";
echo $_POST['nome'] ."<br />";
?>
```

When I click the submit button this is the result:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: the opening tag should be `<?php`

Comment: `<?php`.Not what you've got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<?php` instead of `<php?`

Comment: <?php i changed now but don't run. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the pagina.php file in the same folder? I tried your code and it runs perfect :)

Comment: And what do you mean with "don't run"? When you click on the submit button are you redirected on the pagina.php or not? Did you gain some errors?

Comment: yes when i click the submit button I am redirected on the new pagina, but the reslt is not visible.

Comment: And how looks your url after redirected on the pagina.php? It should looks like
http://localhost/pagina.php?eta=hello&nome=secondHello&send=Invia+Form

Comment: I insert in attachment my url after click button

Comment: This is the solution.  I changed the URL : http://localhost/eta.html  and after run very well. Is important to set localhost in the url. Very thanks.

Comment: Can I set in the script php the URL  localhost/eta.html to start the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need server to execute your php code. Install XAMPP - it is the simplest way how to execute PHP on your localhost.

Comment: But as you said before, that you have htdocs folder, maybe you forgot run Apache server through control panel in XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

On php page..
Write ur code as below

```
     <html>
      <body>
     <?php
   echo $_REQUEST['eta'] ."<br />";
  echo $_REQUEST['nome'] ."<br />";
       ?>
     </body>
               </html>
```

And even use wamp server to check ur php output because php is server side lang.. Wamp is one of the virtaul server soft.. Required and freely available just google it

Answer (score -2):

I would strongly advise you to use 'post'. Why? Because it is a more secure way in many ways. Using 'post' will give you the following script;

html

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="post"> 
    Eta' : <input type="text" name="eta"/> 
    <br> 
    Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/> 
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia Form"/> 
</form>
```

pagina.php

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST['send'] ) ) {
        echo $_POST['eta'] ."<br />";
        echo $_POST['nome'] ."<br />";
}
?>
```

make sure that the 'pagina.php' is in the same location as the html page.

Comment: PHP is a language which has to be compiled by the browser before you can view it. This can be done with a server like Wamp / Xampp, install one of them and try it again. Because the code is working for a 100%. ;)

Comment: I installed Xamp and now? when I put this two file?

Comment: You should go to the htdocs folder, in there you can place your files ( create a folder in there to keep your projects nice and clean ). After that, visit your localhost and search for the file ( example; localhost/sqlTest/index.html ).